# Firing a function after a checkbox is selected in an Angular form

Tags: angular

I have a dynamic form with checkboxes in my Angular 6 app. The following code retrieves the data for my component and populates a reactive form:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.accountsService.getApprovedInvoicesToBeEntered()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.approvedInvoices = result;
        this.controls = this.approvedInvoices.map(c => new FormControl(false));
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          approvedInvoices: new FormArray(this.controls)
        });
      },
      () => { });
}

updateSubtotal() {
  this.selectedTotal  = this.form.value.approvedInvoices
    .map((v, i) => v ? this.approvedInvoices[i] : null)
    .filter(v => v !== null)
    .reduce((a, b) => +a + +b.total, 0);
}
```

}

This is my html:

```html
  <tbody formArrayName="approvedInvoices" *ngFor="let approvedInvoice of approvedInvoices; let i = index">
    <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" (click)="updateSubtotal()" [formControlName]="i" id="{{i}}">
      </td>
    </td>
  </table>
```

This works really well, my problem though is that updateSubtotal doesn't take into account the currently clicked item.  If I have a form with invoices and I click the first one then selectedTotal = 0.  When I select a second invoice, the selectedTotal equals the total of the first invoice.

How can I fire the updateSubtotal() function AFTER the checkbox is marked as selected?

Comment: currently if you click the check box what is happening

Comment: What if you use `(change)` instead of `(click)`?

Comment: Ha,(change) fixed it, I didn't even know that was an option!